# Why my browsers can not show images stored in banners folder?

Tags: image, browser, show

I've stored images of my web application in this path **images/banners**. But my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) can not read and show them. As I rename **banners** to **banner**, this problem solves.
What's the matter ?

Comment: Can you show us some code?! It just sounds wrong....

Comment: @mbinette there is no need to see a picture in a browser. I've just entered their addresses in address bar and nothing happened.

Comment: This is not very precise... :/ From what I understand, you are saying that your files/images are stored in a directory named "banners" but that you can't read them unless you check for a directory names "banner". This doesn't make sense. Unless you show us some code/screencaps/context, we can't really help you..

Comment: I think this is because of some application that is preventing ads to show up. It can be antivirus, or some ad blocker.I think this is becouse of some application that is preventing adds to show up